# VLC plugin for Chrome crash on loading video

Tags: html, vlc

I am making a web application to show various type of content. Video is one of those types.
I installed a VLC on the client computer.

I use this HTML tag to render the video:

```
<object src="infodisplay/getmedia?infoid=${TheModel[0].infoid }&tipe=2"
    type="video/x-ms-wmv"
    width="764" height="573">
</object>
```

After some time chrome's error message popup it says that it can not load the VLC plugin.
But this only happen on this client computer.
It never happen on my laptop.

What would be the problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using Chrome on Win7. The VLC crashes frequently.

Then I switched to Firefox on Ubuntu and use VLC to display video. And the VLC never crashed so far.

Conclusion: VLC and Chrome in Win7 can not reliably work together.

Comment: I'm having same issue but in Linux (Chromium 33.0.1750.152 Ubuntu 12.10). VLC plugin always crashes but in Firefox works fine.